# Using a parameter reference as the optional argument of a macro

Tags: macros, indexing, makeindex

I'm currently trying to get index entries to be automatically shown in italic in the text, i.e. instead of `\textit{Term}\index{Term}`, I want to be able to use `\index{Term}`, which should render the same thing as the first piece of code.

Now so far, I've been able to get *something* similar to work by defining the following macro:

```
\newcommand{\Index}[1]{\textit{#1}\index{#1}}
```

Credit goes to https://www.namsu.de/Extra/pakete/Makeidx.html

Now by using `\Index` (note the capitalized "I"), I partly get the desired result. I cannot, however, use the other possibilities that `index` offers, such as `\index{term@termActuallyDisplayed}`.

My next approach was using:

```
\newcommand{\Index}[2][#2]{\textit{#2}\index{#1@#1}}
```

so that `\Index{Term}` renders `\textit{Term}\index{Term@Term}`, while `\Index[ActualIndexTerm]{Term}` renders `\textit{Term}\index{ActualIndexTerm@ActualIndexTerm}`.

My problem, however, is that using the code above will render an error saying "Illegal parameter number in definition [...]". Hence my question - does anyone know how to circumvent this problem, such as using another package or anything?
(I know that I could just define 2 different commands, but that feels somewhat primitive)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about this: `\newcommand\Index[2][\relax]{\ifx\relax#1\def\actualarg{#2@#2}\else\def\actualarg{#2@#1}\fi\textit{#2}\expandafter\index\expandafter{\actualarg}}`.  P.s.  It would help if you provided a full MWE, and not just a code snippet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This kind of “self-reference” is easy to obtain with [`xparse`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xparse?lang=en):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Index}{O{#2}m}{%
  \textit{#1}\index{#2@#1}%
}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

Here I index `Term': \Index{Term}

Here I index `Actually Used Term' \Index[Actually Used Term]{z}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Adjust to suit; in the example, the second term will be sorted as “z”, so it will appear second.

[image]

The traditional method uses `\@dblarg`:

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\Index}{\@dblarg\@Index}
\def\@Index[#1]#2{%
  \textit{#1}\index{#2@#1}%
}
\makeatother
```

If you want to avoid the problem that `\Index{Term}` and `\index{Term}` will index twice, because the former would do `\index{Term@Term}` that's different from `\index{Term}` to MakeIndex’s point of view, you can modify the command into

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\Index}{om}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
    {\textit{#2}\index{#2}}
    {\textit{#1}\index{#2@#1}}%
}
```

Comment: You're very fast!

Answer (score 4):

EDITED to actually use `\index`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\newcommand\Index[2][\relax]{%
  \ifx\relax#1\def\actualarg{#2@#2}\else\def\actualarg{#2@#1}\fi%
  \textit{#2}%
  \expandafter\index\expandafter{\actualarg}%
}
\makeindex
\begin{document}

\Index{term}

\Index[TermActuallyDisplayed]{term}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The `xparse` package is a great tool which can do what you want (it can declare a command with an optional argument with its default value taken from another argument). See the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\NewDocumentCommand\Index{O{#2}m}{%
  \textit{#2}\index{#2@#1}%
}
\begin{document}

\Index{xyz}

\Index[xyz|textbf]{xyz}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Here both words `xyz` are italicized in the text, and the optional argument can add some additional formatting info for the index itself. The resulting `.idx` file:

```
\indexentry{xyz@xyz}{1}
\indexentry{xyz@xyz|textbf}{1}
```

and `.ind` (basically, the default formatting):

```
\begin{theindex}

  \item xyz, 1, \textbf{1}

\end{theindex}
```

Answer (score 3):

If it is acceptable to slightly change the macro input design to `\Index{...}[...]`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\Index#1{%
  \textit{#1}%
  \kernel@ifnextchar[{\Index@optarg{#1}}{\index{#1@#1}}%
}
\def\Index@optarg#1[#2]{\index{#1@#2}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\Index{Term}

\Index{foo}[bar]
\end{document}
```